# Adding in Module name to template url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using modules within my codeigniter application and PHil Sturgeon's template library and I'm trying to understand my this is happening when I view the source code of my template. Its adding on the string user which is the name of the module.

http://mysite.me/index.php/user/assets/globals/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <title><?php echo $template['title']; ?></title>

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php base_url() ?>assets/globals/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


-application
    -themes
        -mytheme
            -views
                -layouts
                    usermanagement_view.php
```

Comment: What are your settings for `base_url` and `index_page` in `config.php` set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not echoing the base_url(), i.e. not printing it on the page...It should be:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/globals/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Without it, the href attribute gets appended to the segments in the url, that's why you get that result.

Maybe you meant to use the short tag `<?=` , which stands for `<?php echo`. In this case, just don't - they're not always enabled in php.ini, and the 2 chars you spare can be a big hassle when deploying live.

Comment: May I add that base_url() also takes in a value which it will add to the end.

So I'd write <?php echo base_url('assets/globals/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?> instead, for readability.